# Background: Screen Flow Revisited Screen Values

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows, screen-flow

Background: Screen Flow Revisited Screen Values

Screen 1: Inputs (Look up field)

Get Records→

Assign Variables→

Screen 2: Displays default values from the assigned variables

I select "Previous" on Screen 2 to go back and change the Inputs on Screen 1. I also have the Advanced setting option on screen 1 set to "Refresh inputs to incorporate changes else-where in the flow selected."

[image: Revisited Screen Values]

However, when I navigate through and hit Next and go to Screen 2, the original values still remain there? I would like for the new values to be honored in Screen 2. Those default values are associated with variables that should have been updated between screen 1 and 2. Trying to understand why the Advanced Lightning Component setting is not working in this scenario when selecting "Previous" and manually changing the inputs? Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi JB, Presently experiencing similar problem where input data is lost on one particular "back" transition only. If you gained any insight on your problem, and have a minute or two to comment here, please do.