# Flow "Refresh inputs to incorporate changes elsewhere in the flow" problem going back to the first element

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, visual-flows

I have several LWCs linked in a flow where each flow element is configured like this to share the current state of a `Contact` record:

[image: image of config]

i.e.:

- "Manually assign variables" is checked
- "Refresh inputs to incorporate changes elsewhere in the flow" is chosen

Each LWC includes this console logging:

```
    _contact = {};
    @api
    get contact() {
        console.log('RegistrationType get contact ' + JSON.stringify(this._contact));
        return this._contact;
    }
    set contact(c) { 
        console.log('RegistrationType set contact ' + JSON.stringify(c));
        this._contact = c ? { ...c } : {}; 
    }
```

But when going back to the first element that uses the `RegistrationType` LWC from the second element that uses the `RegistrationDetails` LWC, the debug output is:

> RegistrationDetails get contact
> {"Email":"a@b.c","FirstName":"K","RecordTypeId":"0120x000002eG3jAAE","LastName":"C"}
>
> RegistrationType set contact
> {"RecordTypeId":"0120x000002eG3jAAE"}

i.e. a stale value is set on the first element rather than the desired value from the second element.

There is no database interaction here: the aim is to use the flow variables to hold the state until a final "commit" element.

(There is a similar but unanswered question here [Background: Screen Flow Revisited Screen Values](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/363243/background-screen-flow-revisited-screen-values.))

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is working as designed from what I understand, unfortunately. That feature (`refresh inputs`) applies only to when making edits to previous pages and then revisiting *subsequent* elements that leverage those values. When it was added in [Spring '21](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_revisit_screen_values.htm&type=5&release=230), you'll notice the language it used:

> When a user navigates to a previous screen, **then proceeds forward** to a screen that they visited already, the flow can refresh screen component values.

And [Salesforce Scheduler](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ls_refresh_inputs_on_flow_pages.htm&type=5), when they leveraged this feature in their standard flows, only highlight the ability to **make** changes on previous pages:

> Configure your Salesforce Scheduler flows to ensure that **when users go back to a page and make changes** during appointment scheduling, the **changes are reflected on the subsequent pages**.

Your use case, where you want refreshed values when you **navigate backwards** to a previous screen, is not part of this feature.

The scenario this setting applies to is the following:

1. Update Contact in Screen 1
2. Go to Screen 2 and it displays what was in Screen 1
3. Hit previous & re-edit values in Screen 1
4. When you navigate **forward again** to Screen 2, it'll have refreshed values

For *your* scenario, you're hoping it'll refresh going backwards - but, it'll be in "[remember](https://unofficialsf.com/optimizing-lightning-component-inputs-and-outputs-in-flow-screens/)" mode which is what you're noticing (the value it had the last time it visited)

---

So what are your options?

It might not be scalable depending on the complexity of your flow and # of elements - but, you can ensure your flow is always moving forward - even when the user *thinks* they're going backwards.

This would require you to hide the default standard Flow navigation buttons and handle it in your LWC. When they click your "previous" button - you move them forward but set some Boolean output variable that a decision node can leverage to loop to the previous screen element.

```js
handleNext(){
    this.goBack = false;
    const navigateNextEvent = new FlowNavigationNextEvent();
    this.dispatchEvent(navigateNextEvent);
}

handlePrevious(){
    this.goBack = true; //output flow variable used in next decision element
    const navigateNextEvent = new FlowNavigationNextEvent();
    this.dispatchEvent(navigateNextEvent);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kris, and thanks for the work-around option. I had the impression that values were propagated when going "back" later on, but may be wrong about that.

Answer (score 0):

I have Found Work around

After you are done with using screen components somewhere in Flow
Before revisiting same screen use assignment Operator & set Field value NULL or Blank for that fields.

This Should definetly work. I have tried with Object record fields as well.